# When replying to a specific person, is it OK to @ only the first name?

Tags: support

Whenever I make a reply to an answer or a comment I precede my text with @name reference, so the relevant person gets notified. The question is, when a name is comprised of several fields, separated by spaces, do I need to copy all of the fields, or will the first one work as well for the purpose of notification?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to [the blog post that announced the feature](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/01/new-improved-comments-with-reply/):

> Spaces are ignored in the match, so if
>   the person’s display name is “Peter
>   Smith” then just use @peter to match,
>   or @petersmith.

Comment: Thanks! (OK filling the space so I can post the "Thanks!"... ;-)

Comment: @ysap, and if you check now, you'll see there's a little help button next to comments which explains that (and other details). (Note that it also works for two letter first names)